# How to load a file in a directory inside the current working directory

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories

How can I use something like that

```
 NotebookEvaluate[
      "Mathematica\\SomeFile.nb"];
```

Instead of

```
 NotebookEvaluate[
      "B:\\Users\\icemt_000\\Documents\\Mathematica\\SomeFile.nb"];
```

where  `Directory[]`
    is set to `"B:\\Users\\icemt_000\\Documents"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it should just work, but if not use

`NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "Mathematica\\SomeFile.nb"}];`

Also have a look at `NotebookDirectory[]`

Comment: Seems like you've made a typo (wrong position of comma) , this one should be correct `NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{Directory[] , "Mathematica\\SomeFile.nb"}];`
Thanks for help!

Comment: @icemtel Indded. Typo fixed.

Comment: I notice that you have not posted in almost a year.  Have you decided to no longer participate in this community?  I hope not. :-(

Comment: Hi @Mr.Wizard! Huh, is it that long already? I still read the occasional question:) But I've mostly switched to the Python ecosystem for my work-related stuff, so my lack of posts reflects my use of MMA.

Comment: I see.  I am glad you were not soured to this site by something.  It concerns me when longstanding members stop posting, and I always wonder if I could have done something to prevent it.  Are you using something like SageMath?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On the contrary, I believe the MMA.SE is one of the nicest communities on the stackexchange network (and I still wear my t-shirt with pride to various geek meetings:) However my work is mostly numerical, for which MMA is perhaps not the best. I’m using the [Ipython notebook](https://jupyter.org/), numpy and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) as well as [mdtraj](http://mdtraj.org/1.7.2/) and am very satisfied with the setup.

Answer (score 5):

Always better to use `FileNameJoin` than to type in the full path name as a string. Further, you should give the name of each directory in the path individually. So you should use

```
NotebookEvaluate[
  FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "Documents", "Mathematica", "SomeFile.nb"}]]
```

An alternative is not to specify the notebook file, but select it from a system open dialog. This can be done with

```
Module[{path},
  path = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", "*.nb", WindowTitle -> "Select a notebook"];
  If[path === $Canceled, $Canceled, NotebookEvaluate[path]]]
```